# WCF in IIS - Unique URLs per Cusomer

Tags: wcf, iis, endpoints

I'm replacing our old (VB.NET/asmx) service with WCF. We wanted to use WebAPI but have too many customers that still want SOAP. We'll be hosting in IIS 7. (.NET 4.5.2)

Each of our customers (~30) expects their own URL: https://www.example.com/API/4.0/ATT...whatever. I don't anticipate our customer count getting beyond 50 anytime soon.

I know I can accomplish this (as our old service did) by creating a .svc file for each client and (I believe) another endpoint in the config. But from what I've read I think this can be accomplished just through multiple endpoints for one service (the binding and contract/interface are all the same) and that seems much cleaner.

I've made a little progress on this but am running into problems. I'm not asking for help on those problems (yet!) - I'm asking: does anyone have input on whether this is a feasible (or the best?) approach before I dig farther?

Below is a snippet of the config file. I feel like I'm pretty close but if filtering/listenUri is wiser I'll switch tactics.

```
<service name="API" behaviorConfiguration="beUserNameBehavior">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="https://ww6.example.com/API"/>
      <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:55375/"/>-->
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint name="BE" address="/BE" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="beUserNameBinding" contract="API.IBEAPI" />
  <endpoint name="SAP" address="/SAP" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="beUserNameBinding" contract="API.IBEAPI" />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Comment: This way is ok.

Comment: Generally, what you are doing is commonly used as a way to select one of multiple behaviors for a given endpoint, such as requesting a behavior that returns the data in one of many supported formats. If you are going to need to retrieve the value of the entity inside your contract then it may be easier to just add a uritemplate with the entity identifier being part of the route.

Comment: Also, are there any auth schemes in use or is access anonymous?

Comment: If you have only 30 customers depending on your situation it can make sense to have a unique WCF Service for each customer. I have about 40 WCF service running and if you don't touch them maybe once a year after some complex Windows update you have to restart them manually, normally they are just running. Even if you only create one WCF service for all customers you need some active monitoring software (that informs you if something is wrong). You can download some examples from the web. but it's rather simple to write your own monitoring software.

Comment: Ross Bush, I'm using Custom userNamePasswordValidationMode to handle incoming username & password.

Comment: And, yes, we have some customers who would prefer REST access and I suppose multiple-endpoints are how that's done (glanced at a few articles)

And, JRB, actually we'll have even fewer clients than that for the WCF service (I was thinking total clients) so maintaining individual SVC files isn't going to be that much work (though there's still versioning to deal with). I'll go with that approach.